# how to count the duplicates in pandas?

Tags: python, r, pandas

just say I want to check for the duplicates in this df column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
           {"column_with_some_duplicates" : ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c']},
         index = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

in `r` I would check for duplicates like:

```
table(duplicated(df$column_with_some_duplicates))
```

which gives me a table of `true` and 'false' for the boolean result of `duplicated`. How can I view the same thing in pandas? Thanks.

Comment: try: `df['column_with_some_duplicates'].duplicated()`

Comment: https://www.machinelearningplus.com/pandas/pandas-duplicated/

Comment: why would you run `table(duplicated(...))`?? for example `table(duplicated(1:5))` gives FALSE 5. how would that result be of importance? Probably you should consider counting the duplicates ie `table(df$column)`

Comment: `table(duplicated(c('a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c')))` gives FALSE 3 TRUE 2. This how I find out how many duplicates are in my data.

Answer (score 0):

to check if the column provides duplicate values, i will suggest to do a function

you could use the builtin `set` class, wich eliminates the duplicates, re-transforming it to a `list`, and then checking for equality:

```
def isduplicate(df,col):
    return list(set(df[col]))==list(col)
```

or you could just use the `.duplicated()` method:

```
def isduplicate(df,col):
    return df[col].duplicated()
```

a different approach would be to use the lenght of the unique elements.

```
def is_duplicate(df,col):
    return len(df[col].unique())<len(df[col])
```